# Spinner selected Item doesnt show in Fragment

Tags: java, android, api, android-layout, spinner

Im developing an app that has 2 Spinners in a Horizontal LinearLayout.
I can fill the spinners dropdowns with the items that came from a webservice but when i select the item in the dropdown it doesnt show up in the "input" of the spinner. I'm using a "wrap_content" and this makes this input adapt to the empty input, its like there is text but it doesnt show up. I'm missing something?

i thinks that maybe is the WebService filling the Spinner or because im using the spinner in a fragment.

I've tried changing the color, creating a new layout just for the spinner item, changing the backgroundcolor, changing the width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is wondering how to solve this problem, you have to get de json in the asynctask doInBackground and then you have to fill the spinner in onPostExecute.